# Creating array object and calling recursion method to display sum

Tags: java, arrays, string, recursion, methods

I'm trying to figure out how to properly create an instance of an object that would be an int array. Also, once I have done so I want to try to display the array as a string and then display the sum from my recursion method so that I can test my object class.

***THE MAIN CLASS...***

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectClass[] numArray = new ObjectClass[]; //trying to create new object so I can use toString method

        numArray.toString(); //calling toString method?
        numArray.recursionSum();
    }
}
```

***THE OBJECT CLASS...***

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class ObjectClass {

    int[] numArray = {10,10,20,20,40};

    public int[] getArray() { //this is my accessor method
        return numArray;
    }

    public int[] setArray(int[] newa) { //this is my mutator method
        this.numArray = newa;
        return this.numArray;
    }

    public String toString() { //this is my toString method
        return Arrays.toString(numArray);
    }

    public int recursionSum(int[] numArray, int n) { // this is the recursive method that returns sum of array elements
        if (n == 0)
            return numArray[n];
        else
            return numArray[n] + recursionSum(numArray, n-1);
    }

}
```

Comment: You appear to be over-complicating things. It's not `ObjectClass[] numArray = new ObjectClass[];` but rather much more simply `ObjectClass numArray = new ObjectClass();`

Comment: That helped on my initial errors, but now I get an error that says "The method recursionSum(int[], int) in the type ObjectClass is not applicable for the arguments ()"

Comment: then fix the error. It appears self-explanatory, no? --i.e., the error message is telling you *exactly* what you're doing wrong -- read it critically and use it help you fix your code.

Comment: i would change to something like? numArray.recursionSum(numArray, ?) i dont know what to pass for the int

Comment: your `ObjectClass` already contains an array. `ObjectClass numArray = new ObjectClass()` will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not passing the array into a class I think you should create another method to start the recursion and return the result.
E.g.

```
public int recursionSum() {
  return recursionSum(numArray, numArray.length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.new `ObjectClass`**

**2.use `setArray` 、 `getArray` and `recursionSum` method in your main .**

Try this .

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ObjectClass init
        ObjectClass objectClass = new ObjectClass();
        // int[]
        int n = 1;
        int[] numArray = {10,10,20,20,40};
        // set array
        objectClass.setArray(numArray);
        // toString method
        System.out.println(objectClass.toString());
        // you can change numArray and n
        System.out.println(objectClass.recursionSum(objectClass.getArray(),n));
    }
}
```